# Selecting Multiple Fields in a Find Statement SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So basically, I am trying to select a row from my database, based on two values, I have tried doing 
`SELECT FROM users WHERE first = 'Bob' AND last = 'Stevenson'`;

but when I do it it gives this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM users WHERE first = 'Robert' AND last = 'Westbury'' at line 1

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Comment: Please refer to docs [13.2.9 SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Comment: you need to select `columns` or `*` in order to get data like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE first='Bob' AND last = 'Stevenson'`

Comment: You have to specify what you want to select. For excemple 'SELECT first, last FROM...' or if you want to get everything simply do 'SELECT * FROM...

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify what column(s) do you want to select, `SELECT` statement should be followed by the column names or by `*` to select all the columns:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first = 'Bob' AND last = 'Stevenson'
```

Comment: ... except, of course, that you should never use evil 'SELECT *'

Answer (score 0):

Dude, it's `Select (* OR <column_name_1>, <column_name_2>... ) From <table_name> where <condition>;`